# Converting a multilevel array into a string by the condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Please help convert data to properly format probably use reduce method

`const testData = { a: [1], b: [2, 3, 4], c: [] };`

should be  a=1&b=2,3,4
returned   a=1&b=2,3,4&

```
const createUrlString = params =>
    Object.keys(params)
        .map(
            attr => (params[attr].length ? `${attr}=${params[attr].join(',')}` : '')
        )
        .join('&');

const testData = { a: [1], b: [2, 3, 4], c: [] };
const filterString = createUrlString(testData);
```

Comment: sandbox link https://repl.it/@avitusr/DistortedSnarlingMethod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `array#map` you can use `array#reduce`. For array values which are empty you are inserting `''` string which is why `array#join` is adding `&` at the end.

```js
const testData = { a: [1], b: [2, 3, 4], c: [] };
var result = Object.keys(testData).reduce((r,k) => {
  if(Array.isArray(testData[k]) && testData[k].length) {
    r.push(`${k}=${testData[k].join(',')}`);
  }
  return r;
},[]).join('&');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

"filter" method would do the work.

```
const createUrlString = params =>
    Object.keys(params)
        .map(
            attr => (params[attr].length ? `${attr}=${params[attr].join(',')}` : '')
        )
        .filter(paramStr => paramStr)
        .join('&');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries),  to convert object to multidimensional array

```
Object.entries({ foo: 'bar', baz: 42 });
```

will return

```
[ ['foo', 'bar'], ['baz', 42] ]
```

See the code below:

```js
const createUrlString = params =>
  Object.entries(params)
    .map( el => el[0]+"="+el[1].join(","))
    .join('&');

const testData = {
  a: [1],
  b: [2, 3, 4],
  c: []
};
const filterString = createUrlString(testData);
console.log(filterString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the data first:

```
const testData = { a: [1], b: [2, 3, 4], c: [] };
let filteredData = Object.entries(testData).filter(t => t[1].length > 0);//Filter empty values
var result = filteredData.map(t => {
    t[1].join(',');
    return t.join('=');
}).join('&');
```

Answer (score -1):

append & always with nonempty and at end remove last one

```
const createUrlString = params =>
    Object.keys(params)
        .map(
            attr => (params[attr].length ? `${attr}=${params[attr].join(',')}&` : '')
        )
        .join('');

const testData = { a: [1], b: [2, 3, 4], c: [] };
const filterString = createUrlString(testData);
console.log(filterString.slice(0,filterString.length-1));
```